# Is it possible to fecth all images in a profile from facebook?

Tags: php, zend-framework, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to write a facebook application in Zend Framework, where I want to fetch all the images saved in a profile.

Is it possible?

Please help me......

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, look at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ (the `photos` and `albums` collections.)